# MongoDB query for two input arrays at same index?

Tags: mongodb

I have two arrays A and B of length `n` defined by the input,

`fruit_ids = [{id: "id1"}, {id: "id2"}, {id:"id3"}]; 
fruit_names = [{name: "Orange"},{name: "Kiwi"},{name: "Banana"}]`

and MongoDB documents

```
{ farm_id: "3344", fruits: [{name: "Orange", id:"id1"}, {name: "Kiwi", id:"id67"}]}
```

Now I want to write a Mongo query such that it pulls items from particular farm_id specified at array `fruit_ids` and `fruit_names` but at same index,

for example for the above input, I want for `farm_id: 3344` `{name: "Orange", id:"id1"}` to get deleted.

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$pullAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) operator to remove all the matching elements and build your update statement dynamically using below code:

```
var fruit_ids = [{id: "id1"}, {id: "id2"}, {id:"id3"}]; 
var fruit_names = [{name: "Orange"},{name: "Apple"},{name: "Banana"}];

var pullAll = {
    $pullAll: { fruits: fruit_ids.map((id, index) => Object.assign(fruit_names[index], id)) }
}

db.col.update({ farm_id: 3344 }, pullAll)
```

This will only try to update the `farm_id: 3344`.

Comment: and where is $pull in you query.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur apologies for that, I saw query in your description but if you just want to update your collection then please check my updated answer

Comment: But I want to update only for `farm_id: 3344`, not mutiple documents only for one farm_id.

Comment: I will just add `farm_id: 3344` instead of `{}` and will remove multi?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur yes, that's how I just modified my answer

Comment: Can you please tell me one thing, why when I am using $PushAll then inside all objects present in the array, default values are getting added, because of which $pullAll is not removing any embedded document. Can you please tell me how can I remove them.

Comment: I found that there is a property in mongoose `setDefaultsOnInsert`, but there is no property for pull/remove which can work for us.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102691/pullall-while-removing-embedded-objects See this answer, I think $PullAll don't work on Embedded docs, it only works on array.

Comment: Are you there ?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur $pullAll works fine in a case descrbied here cause you can build your embedded documents from two arrays which answers the question. If you have any other cases please open a separate question and someone will try to anser that

Comment: thanks for helping, actually the problem happening is $pullAll works with exact matching, that's why I am having this problem, is there any workaround for this instead of writing bulkwrite query with $pull multiple times, thanks for helping, please reply :)

Comment: Hey I have found the solution, thanks anyway for helping cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying `$pullAll` as suggested by @mickl in his answer, but the thing is I had other fields inside my embedded documents and because `$pullAll` works only for **exact matches**, that's why I currently I am using `$pull` with `$or` on the array of embedded docs. I found this solution from this answer [how-to-force-mongodb-pullall-to-disregard-document-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776617/how-to-force-mongodb-pullall-to-disregard-document-order).

```
let arr = [{name: "Orange", id:"id1"}, {name: "Kiwi", id:"id67"}];

db.col.update(
    { farm_id: 3344 },
    { "$pull": { "fruits": { "$or": arr } }}
)
```